# PHP multiple OR in if condition

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to check in my PHP code if my user has the necessary rights to perform an action but my conditions wont work. I'm probably misunderstanding the AND/OR. May I require your help please.

Actually, I have :

```
if ( !in_array('ADMIN',$_SESSION['roles']) || !in_array('MANAGEMENT',$_SESSION['roles']) || $requester != $_SESSION['tnumber'] ) {
                            echo "you are not allowed to XXXX !";
                    } else {
      // allowed
}
```

I've put these 3 conditions with ORs (||) but it's failing.

What I want to say is :

1. If the user doesn't have 'ADMIN' or 'MANAGEMENT' rights (value in the `$SESSION['roles']` array)
2. Or if the user is not the requester (`$requester` should be the same as `$_SESSION['tnumber']`

Then he should have a message saying that he's not allowed.

Otherwise (if he's got ADMIN rights, or MANAGEMENT rights, or he is the requester), then it should work.

How can I change my condition to fulfill this request ?

Thanks, 
Regards!

Comment: Why don't you just make two nested IF-Statements out of it?

Comment: try using echo $_SESSION['roles'] and $_SESSION['tnumber'] and $requester to find out the values you are getting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a condition like `if (p || q || r)`, the whole `if` statement evaluates to `true` if at least one of the three conditions is `true`. If you don't have MANAGEMENT role, then `!in_array('MANAGEMENT',$_SESSION['roles'])` will be `true`, hence access will be denied.

I would recommend you to invert the `if` statement, so that if true, the access is granted, otherwise it's denied. So:

```
if (in_array('ADMIN', $_SESSION['roles']) || in_array('MANAGEMENT', $_SESSION['roles']) || $requester == $_SESSION['tnumber'] ) {
    // allowed
} else {
    // denied
}
```

It will also help the readability of your code if you extract the big condition to a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have it backwards, you need

```
if(!$admin && !$management && ...){
  echo 'Not allowed';
}
```

Or you can have

```
if($admin || $management || ...){
  echo 'Allowed';
}
```