# PHP if statement strpos === false with an or ||

Tags: php, if-statement, strpos

I'm trying to get the if statement to echo equals true but it equals false. What am I doing wrong?

sometimes $line-2 will be 5% and sometimes it will be 0%. So it varies like that. How would I write the if statement for both cases?

So basically, I want it to echo equal true if the variable line_2 is 0% or is 5%. I only want it to echo equals false if the variable is anything other than 0% or 5%.

```
$line_2 = '5%'; // this will be random. Can be 0%. Can be 5%. Can be 25%.

if (strpos($line_2, '5') === false || strpos($line_2, '0') === false) {
    echo 'equals false';
} else {
    echo 'equals true';
}
```

more clarification.

Where it says `echo 'equals false'` there is actually a command there to execute another php script. I need that script to be executed only if `line_2` does not equal 5% or it does not equal 0%.

Hope that sums it up.

Comment: because your second OR condition strpos($line_2, '0') is returning false

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP multiple OR in if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40417916/php-multiple-or-in-if-condition)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya sometimes $line-2 will be 5% and sometimes it will be 0%. So it varies like that. How would I write the if statement for both cases?

Comment: check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52263221/2469308
you need to reverse your strpos check.

Comment: Some clarification... You want it to `echo true` if `$line_2` = `%5` or `%2` ...?

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya `echo true` if `$line_2` = 5% or if it = 0%.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya please see edit in post for clarification.

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya please see edit in post for clarification.

Comment: @Mike ... I posted an answer. Check it out. Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: @Mike my answer already handles your requirements. You may check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from a misunderstanding of the way you negate conditional statements.

You mention that you want to echo `true` if `$line_2` contains a `0` OR a `5`; however, your if statement checks the opposite condition to echo `false` and will echo `true` if the condition fails. So we need to change the condition from `if line contains 0 or line contains 5` to `if not (line contains 0 or line contains 5)`.

The way you accomplish this is by considering [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Specifically, when you distribute negation across logical OR or logical AND, the following holds true:

- `not (A OR B) = (not A) AND (not B)`
- `not (A AND B) = (not A) OR (not B)`

That is, you distribute the negation and change the logical operator to its opposite.

In this case, since you want to accomplish `not (line contains 0 or line contains 5)`, you should distribute it such that you obtain `(not line contains 0) and (not line contains 5)`, which looks like this:

```
$line_2 = '5%'; // this will be random. Can be 0%. Can be 5%. Can be 25%.

if (strpos($line_2, '5') === false && strpos($line_2, '0') === false) {
    echo 'equals false';
} else {
    echo 'equals true';
}
```

The problem with your current code is that you instead have a solution resembling `if (not line contains 0) or (not line contains 5)`. The difference between the two is only in the logical operator connecting the two conditions, where you're using `or` but should really be using `and`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP's edit, you should reverse your if condition check logic. Do the following:

```
$line_2 = '5%'; // Or it can be 0%

if (strpos($line_2, '5') !== false || strpos($line_2, '0') !== false) {
    echo 'equals true'; // 0 or 5 is found in the string
} else {
    echo 'equals false';
}
```

Comment: `strpos()` may return a `0` to indicate that the target exists and is at the beginning of the string. If the target is not found, then `strpos()` returns `false`. You're excluding a valid position of `0`. This cannot be fixed with `>=`, either, because `false >= 0` will evaluate to `true` due to type coercion. The condition absolutely must check `strpos(...) === false` or `strpos(...) !== false`.

Comment: @B.Fleming Thanks. Edited

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `strpos()` for this unless `$line_2` might sometimes contain more strings.

```
<?php

$line_2 = '5%';

$statement = 'equals false';    //Set the default message
if ($line_2 === '5%' || $line_2 === '%0') {  //Check if $line_2 equals 5% or 2%. Note the strong comparison since $line_2 is a string.
    $statement = 'equals true';
}

echo $statement;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `&&` instead

Using the OR operator in that if statement will return true if that character is '5' OR '0'

So, because`strpos($line_2, '0') === false` will return `true`, your statement will become

`if(false || true)`

thus echoing 'equals false', whereas using AND

`if(false && true)`

will be false, giving you 'equals true'